# Are these star - black hole binary pair illustrations art or physics?

Tags: accretion-disk

It seems that every illustration of a black hole pulling matter off a star looks like this one from the [Chandra X-ray Observatory](https://chandra.harvard.edu/xray_sources/blackholes_stellar.html) website.

[image]

Or this one from Nature - [Two black holes found in a star cluster](https://www.nature.com/articles/490046a) (Pay walled)

[image]

Two things bother me about this kind of illustration.

First the stream of matter being sucked off the star looks like a taffy pull. On a galactic scale, I could understand this. Over time, an unstructured elliptical galaxy develops bars and spiral arms from self gravitation.

But here matter is pulled off by tidal forces. At the nearest area of the stars surface, the attraction from the black hole exceeds the attraction from the star. Once separated from the star, this matter should follow an orbit around the black hole, not fall straight in. Being hot gas, atoms have a range of speeds and directions. Some would head toward the black hole. I would not expect self gravitation to pull it together like this. The solar wind shows no signs of this kind of organization. If anything, I would expect the accretion disk to extend to the star.

Second, the accretion disk is flat like Saturn's rings. I can understand how rotating dust and gas would flatten itself in a protoplanetary system or around a planet. But as it falls in, it is compressed and heated to millions of degrees. It isn't like a near vacuum protoplanet. Pressure is high. Would it flatten under these circumstances, or would pressure push gas above and below the orbital plane?

It seems that these illustrations must be an artist's vision. But they appear in scientific contexts. I rarely see anything different. So is it realistic? If so, what is the explanation?

Comment: Are you picturing the stills as depictions of a moment in a roughly stable circular orbit? I think the taffy pull thing is supposed to be after the star's point of nearest approach in a very eccentric orbit, in which it is smeared out with tidal forces, the smeared star continues away from the black hole on the receding end of the eccentric orbit, and rounds out into a big hot cloud much bigger and less dense than the initial star under self-gravitaiton as the expanding smear falls away from the black hole and slows down.

Comment: Or at least that makes sense to me as the origin of the image, before sequential artists rendered it in a sort of artistic game of Telephone.

Comment: Here is my artist's rendition of what I think the artists are rendering https://imgur.com/a/AoykJBt

Comment: @gs - Its a thought. But the same thing must be happening in the accretion disk. Why does the narrow "bridge" look so much different from the accretion disk?

Comment: The general idea of the picture makes sense to me when I think about the disk as a record of the history of the star's high velocity, low distance interaction with the star, not a prediction of the future of the "bridge". I would expect the future of the bridge to get longer, smear-i-er, and dimmer, break apart into a few smear-y clouds (with the part near the Hot Blob ending up as part of the Hot Blob and the part near to the black hole ending up in the disk), and dissipate, not get slurped into the accretion disk continuously like a cosmic bowl of ramen.

Comment: The second little orange red "galaxy arm" on the first image doesn't make sense to me either. But all this is just guesses and intuitions, not expertise and conclusions - hence comments and suggestions, not an answer, even a tentative one. When I run the interaction as an imaginary video in my brain that's how it looks.